# How to modify a Serialized variable from a Custom Editor script in Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, editor

I have a test script with 1 Serialized string and i am trying to access and modify it by typing something to the TextField but i dont know what to assign the TextField to.

Test Script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string value;

}
```

TestTool Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Test))]
public class TestTool : Editor
{
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{

    base.OnInspectorGUI();

    Rect textFieldRect = new Rect(EditorGUILayout.GetControlRect(false, EditorGUIUtility.currentViewWidth));

    EditorGUI.DrawRect(textFieldRect, Color.gray);

    EditorGUI.TextField(textFieldRect, "Type here...");
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would **not** recommend to directly change the value using

```
Test myTest = (Test)target;
myTest.value = EditorGUI.TextField(textFieldRect, myTest.value);
```

Instead use [`SerializedProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.PropertyField.html)

```
private SerializedProperty _value;

private void OnEnable()
{
    // Link the SerializedProperty to the variable 
    _value = serializedObject.FindProperty("value");
}

public override OnInspectorGUI()
{
    // fetch current values from the target
    serializedObject.Update();

    EditorGUI.PropertyField(textFieldRect, _value);

    // Apply values to the target
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedValues();
}
```

The huge advantage of that is that Undo/Redo and marking Scene and class as "dirty" is all handled automatically and you don't have to do it manually.

However to make this work variables have always to be either `public` or `[SerializedField]` which is already the case in your class.

Instead of the `rect` I would actually recommend you rather use [`EditorGUILayout.PropertyField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.PropertyField.html) and set the sizes via [`GUILayout.ExpandWidth`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.ExpandWidth.html) and [`GUILayout.ExpandHeight`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.ExpandHeight.html) or the others available under

**options**

> GUILayout.Width,
>     GUILayout.Height,
>     GUILayout.MinWidth, 
>     GUILayout.MaxWidth,
>     GUILayout.MinHeight, 
>     GUILayout.MaxHeight,
>     GUILayout.ExpandWidth, 
>     GUILayout.ExpandHeight.

In order to not show a label use `GUIContent.none`.

So it might look like

```
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_value, GUIContent.none, GUILayout.ExpandHeight, GUILayout.ExpandWith);
```

Comment: When the Rect is small it doesn't work and how can i make it not show the name of the property? it also messes up the Rect because of the name. http://prntscr.com/lgh2sa http://prntscr.com/lgh2ff

Comment: I updated my answer. But I realised now you actually draw it using a rect inside another frame. On your first image in the question it looked a bit different. But you can use also simply `GUIContent.none` for the `EditorGUI` version

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Test myTest = (Test)target;
myTest.value = EditorGUI.TextField(textFieldRect, myTest.value);
```

`target` is a property supplied via the Editor superclass and contains a reference to whatever object instance is being inspected.